# openGL crashing when calling glGenBuffers

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glew

I'm learning OpenGL via http://learnopengl.com/ however I am crashing when I am trying to bind the buffers in the 'hello triangle' part of the tutorial. I have prior coding experience in C++ but I can't work out what is wrong.

My Code:

```
#include <iostream>

#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glfw3.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>

using namespace std;



const GLuint WIDTH = 800, HEIGHT = 600;

void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mode);
int initializeWindow(GLFWwindow* window);
int main() {

    GLFWwindow* window;

    cout << "Creating Triangles" << endl;
    GLfloat triangles[] = {
            -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
             0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
             0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f
    };

    cout << "Initialising GLFW" << endl;
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

    cout << "Initialising Window..." << endl;
    window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "LearnOpenGL", NULL, NULL);

    cout << "Setting Callback Functions..." << endl;
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);

    cout << "Binding Buffers" << endl;
    GLuint VBO;
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO); // <--- Crashing here
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(triangles), triangles, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    if (initializeWindow(window) == -1) {
        return -1;
    }

    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glfwPollEvents();

        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }

    cout << "Terminating..." << endl;
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

int initializeWindow(GLFWwindow* window) {

        if (window == NULL) {
            cout << "Failed to create GLFW window... exiting" << endl;
            glfwTerminate();
            return -1;
        }

        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

        glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
        if(glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
            cout << "Failed to initialize GLEW... exiting" << endl;
            return -1;
        }

        int width, height;
        glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);
        glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

        return 0;
}

void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mode) {
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS) {
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
    }
}
```

I am getting just a generic 'not responding' crash, no errors in the console. Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `initializeWindow` just after the window creation and before any call to gl functions. This is necessary in order to make current windows active and initialize glew (these operations are done inside `initializewindow`)

Comment: ahh of cause, I completely forgot I initialise the window inside the if statement. thanks!